# Draw/erase button in java

Tags: java, netbeans

I am struggling to find a way to implement a way that whenever you click a draw button it will decide whether you are drawing or erasing.

```
 private void drawButtonActionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        solveButton.setEnabled(true);

        slider.setEnabled(true);

        captureButton.setEnabled(true);

    }
```

My code at the moment lets automatically decides whether to draw or erase based on whether there is an obstacle where you are clicking

```
 private class MouseHandler implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

        int cur_row, cur_col, cur_val;



        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {


            int row = (evt.getY() - 10) / squareSize;
            int col = (evt.getX() - 10) / squareSize;
            if (row >= 0 && row < rows && col >= 0 && col < columns) {

                cur_row = row;
                cur_col = col;
                cur_val = grid[row][col];

                if (cur_val == EMPTY) {
                    grid[row][col] = OBST;
                }
                if (cur_val == OBST) {
                    grid[row][col] = EMPTY;
                }
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {

            int row = (evt.getY() - 10) / squareSize;
            int col = (evt.getX() - 10) / squareSize;
            if (row >= 0 && row < rows && col >= 0 && col < columns) {

                if ((row * columns + col != cur_row * columns + cur_col) && (cur_val == STARTNODE || cur_val == ENDNODE)) {
                    int new_val = grid[row][col];
                    if (new_val == EMPTY) {
                        grid[row][col] = cur_val;
                        if (cur_val == STARTNODE) {
                            startnodeStart.row = row;
                            startnodeStart.col = col;
                        } else {
                            endnodePos.row = row;
                            endnodePos.col = col;
                        }
                        grid[cur_row][cur_col] = new_val;
                        cur_row = row;
                        cur_col = col;
                        if (cur_val == STARTNODE) {
                            startnodeStart.row = cur_row;
                            startnodeStart.col = cur_col;
                        } else {
                            endnodePos.row = cur_row;
                            endnodePos.col = cur_col;
                        }
                        cur_val = grid[row][col];
                    }
                } else if (grid[row][col] != STARTNODE && grid[row][col] != ENDNODE) {
                    grid[row][col] = OBST;
                }

            }

            repaint();

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        }

    }
```

Pls help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read the code (its very long and unclear), but if you want to do what i think you want to do(have a program in wich you can draw and then earse what you drew) you can just draw circles of a certain color in the x and y of your mouse when the mouse button is being presssed. When you want to earse you just do the same thing with background color.